# Developer mode issue

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

I`m facing following issue:

My stack is LEMP and Magento 2 is running without any problems, but-but-but...

While trying to switch into developer mode, using bin/magento file, the output informs me about successful switching, but still no exceptions are on the screen.

While I'm making typo in core files for a reason, I just see 500 error, and everything that I desire to make visible on the screen is just logged into the `system.log` file.

Please advice me.

Permissions are 777 for now, until I'll find the way to see the exceptions. I do not have declaration of the mode in `.htaccess` file and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/magento.conf`.

When I'm running `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` - it displays that I'm already in developer mode.

Here is output in `system.log`:

> [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_106f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles
>   catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  []
>   []
>       [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_10c7461af04bb11fe209659d7147d2c579 and handles
>   default, cms_index_index, cms_page_view, cms_index_index_id_home:
>   Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
>       [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_100a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441 and handles
>   1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
>       [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>       [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>       [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>       [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>       [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>       [2016-12-18 17:22:54] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_106f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles
>   catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  []
>   []
>       [2016-12-18 17:23:07] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_10d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles
>   : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

But it is not the one I want. I want to reach seeing the following in the browser:

> 2016/12/18 19:21:22 [error] 9905#9905: *372 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   /var/www/magento2/app/autoload.php on line 23 PHP message: PHP Stack
>   trace: PHP message: PHP   1. {main}()
>   /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php:0 PHP message: PHP   2. require()
>   /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php:13" while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.newmagento.com, request: "GET
>   /admin/admin/cache/index/key/eafa4895505340712c8f26a49e451a246334ffe5e50cd75ddc79352ecabc36ef/
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock:",
>   host: "www.newmagento.com"

But I can find it only in `error.log` of my nginx.

Comment: Any error in `system.log` file?

Comment: Nothing there. All logs are clean as pure child =)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you. In system.log THERE are errors, and other lines about successful parsing. But all the others logs are empty

Comment: Can you update your question with the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to throw an exceptions before error handler was initialized.
So, that`s the solution.

If you want to check if the developer mode is really working for you - throw an exception in  /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php, after 255 line where error handler is initialized.
For example paste this. Exception`s text was picked up randomly from allowed by M2.

```
$myVar = 1;
if ($myVar == 1) {
    throw new \Exception('We can\'t read some files that are required to run the Magento application. ' . 'This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly.');
            }
```